# convert nested arrays to object in these arrays

Tags: javascript

I have one question about converting arrays to the objects. Look on two array in array:

```
[ 
  [ 'answer 1 question 1',
    'answer 2 question 1',
    'answer 3 question 1',
    'answer 4 question 1' 
  ],
  [ 'answer 1 question 2',
    'answer 2 question 2',
    'answer 3 question 2',
    'answer 4 question 2' 
  ] 
]
```

And please explain me how I can convert this arrays to the following format:

```
[ 
  [ 
   {'name': 'answer 1 question 1'},
   {'name': 'answer 2 question 1'},
   {'name': 'answer 3 question 1'},
   {'name': 'answer 4 question 1'} 
  ],
  [ 
   {'name': 'answer 1 question 2'},
   {'name': 'answer 2 question 2'},
   {'name': 'answer 3 question 2'},
   {'name': 'answer 4 question 2'}
  ] 
]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why they are in that format to begin with? The less transformation you use the better off you will be in the long run.

Comment: show us your attempt first so we can help alter it to a solution that works best for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through items and convert strings to objects:

```js
{
  const arr = [ 
    [ 'answer 1 question 1',
      'answer 2 question 1',
      'answer 3 question 1',
      'answer 4 question 1' 
    ],
    [ 'answer 1 question 2',
      'answer 2 question 2',
      'answer 3 question 2',
      'answer 4 question 2' 
    ] 
  ]

  console.log(
    arr.map(arr => arr.map(
      item => ({name: item})
    ))
  )
  /* OUTPUT:
  [ 
    [ 
     {'name': 'answer 1 question 1'},
     {'name': 'answer 2 question 1'},
     {'name': 'answer 3 question 1'},
     {'name': 'answer 4 question 1'} 
    ],
    [ 
     {'name': 'answer 1 question 2'},
     {'name': 'answer 2 question 2'},
     {'name': 'answer 3 question 2'},
     {'name': 'answer 4 question 2'}
    ] 
  ]
  */
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I try learn javascript but sometimes I have no enough knowledge

Comment: If i have second array, the same but against 'name' will 'boolean' and true false values. Is possible to merge tese array that result will be {'name';'xyz', 'boolean'; true/false} ? I tried use Object.assign() but not working good

Answer (score 3):

```js
const startArr = [ 
  [ 'answer 1 question 1',
    'answer 2 question 1',
    'answer 3 question 1',
    'answer 4 question 1' 
  ],
  [ 'answer 1 question 2',
    'answer 2 question 2',
    'answer 3 question 2',
    'answer 4 question 2' 
  ] 
];

const resultArr = startArr.map(answers => answers.map(answer => ({name: answer})));
console.log(resultArr);
```

For array transformation the best solution is to use **.map** which allows to create new version of array without touching old one and without need to have temporary state variables. Function **.map** is one of immutable Array object functions.

In this case we need to go through main array and map it into result of the mapping of nested answers array. We are simply transforming every element of answers array from a string to an object.

Answer (score 2):

A more verbose, basic version omitting `Array.map`:

```js
var txtArr = [ 
  [ 'answer 1 question 1',
    'answer 2 question 1',
    'answer 3 question 1',
    'answer 4 question 1' 
  ],
  [ 'answer 1 question 2',
    'answer 2 question 2',
    'answer 3 question 2',
    'answer 4 question 2' 
  ] 
]

var objArr = [], tmpArr = []

txtArr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(subitem) {
    tmpArr.push({ name: subitem })
  })
  objArr.push(tmpArr)
  tmpArr = []
})

console.log(objArr)
```

Comment: Well, I don't think it's more verbose. Read about work of working memory.

”The average human brain has only a few shared resources for discrete quanta in working memory, and each variable potentially consumes one of those quanta. As you add more variables, our ability to accurately recall the meaning of each variable is diminished. Working memory models typically involve 4–7 discrete quanta.” ~ Eric Eliott